# R function ordistep for variable selection

Tags: r, function, variables, selection

The first problem I have come across is I need to select variables for a RDA in R and using two different functions (`forward.sel` from *pack.for* and `ordistep` from *vegan*). I get two different results even if I'm using the same parameters. The second problem is `ordistep` returns varying results from time to time when I enter the same code line. The function `forward.sel` always returns the same selection of 3 variables whereas the function `ordistep` returns 1, 2 or 3 variables that are changing each time I re-enter the same code line.

Specifically, I'm using data on plant root productivity and a variety of environmental conditions and trying to see which environmental conditions influences productivity parameters.

When using `forward.sel` I get soil's volumetric water content, pH and soil C,

```
test=forward.sel(variables[,1:3], #productivity variables#
                 variables[,4:length(variables)], #environmental variables#
                 nperm = 999, alpha = 0.1)
```

When using `ordistep` I sometimes get soil P, soil N and pH, sometimes soil's volumetric water content, soil N , soil P, and pH,  or a mix of those variables in varying order.

```
mod0=rda(variables[,1:3]~1,variables[,4:length(variables)])
mod1=rda(variables[,1:3]~.,variables[,4:length(variables)])

test2=ordistep(mod0, scope = formula(mod1),
               direction=c("forward"), Pin=0.1, perm.max = 9999)
```

I may be doing something wrong in selecting constrains for `ordistep` because it varies too much from time to time even when I'm using 9999 data permutations. I'd like to know if you can explain those variations in the results.

Comment: Where do you get package pack.for? It is not in CRAN nor in R-Forge. I would like to see how it handles setting random number seed. I would also like to know how do you know that results differ "too much". Chances are that results of pack.for differ "too little", but we cannot reproduce your case without your data. NB., argument 'perm.max' in `ordistep` sets the **maximum** number of permutations, but not the actual number. Use argument 'pstep' if you want to set the minimum number.

Comment: Oh i'm so sorry I forgot to include the link. 
http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=195
The function forward.sel mimics the canoco forward function.

Comment: Thank you for your comments mr. Oksanen (it is an honor to get help from the master himself). You are right, I can't really say if it really differs too much but out of ten times i enter the code line i get :

1) VWC + N + Conc.H + P2O5 

2) P2O5 + Conc.H + N + K + CEC + MO

3) VWC + N + P2O5 + Conc.H 

4) P2O5 + N + Conc.H + K + CEC + MO

5) P2O5 + N + Conc.H + K + CEC + MO

6) VWC + N + P2O5 + Conc.H 

7) VWC + C + Conc.H 

8) VWC + C + Conc.H

9) VWC + N + P2O5 + Conc.H

10) P2O5 + N + Conc.H + K + CEC + MO
I see there seems to be globally two different outcomes to the variable selection

Comment: OK, thanks for the address (I forgot this was in R-forge). It seems that the **packfor** package uses C function `rand()` for random numbers, but does not set its seed. At least with my version of `rand()` this means that the random numbers always have the same seed and generate the same sequence. This explains why **packfor** results do not change: they are the same random permutation. In **vegan** random numbers change unless you set the same seed. If your predictor data are multicollinear, the selection can be very unstable. Use `vif.cca()` (in **vegan**) function to see multicollinearity.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Oksanen, 
Indeed when I control for colinearity before the variable selection, both forward.sel and ordi.step give similar results and ordistep seems to be returning results that are more constant from time to time. I was controlling colinearity only on the results of the variable selection and then modifying the selection accordingly. Again, thank you for your very appreciated help.